# Magento2: How to move featured products first in search result?

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, search-criteria

I want to sort the product search results by featured attribute(Yes/No type) so featured product comer first then show non-featured products. Currently, my search result is mixing in featured & non-featured items.

**Ex:** If the user searches the product, search results if any product assigned as featured that products come first and rest of the products after featured products.

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento2: I want to show featured product on top of the category and search result](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302356/magento2-i-want-to-show-featured-product-on-top-of-the-category-and-search-resu)

Comment: @yash that is for move featured product on top in category page, I want same in search result

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302031/magento-2-change-default-orderby-parameter-for-search-results/304034#304034, might give you some hints

Comment: @Yash: thanks for your comment this solution work for me.